# Plotly does not work in shiny with HTML function

Tags: html, r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I'm dealing with a quite complicated shiny app in which I would like to create an UI output inside server function. UI is not that easy and depends on many items created on a server side so I'm creating it concatenating HTML parts of UI. Everything works until I meet `plotly` chart.

I've created a simpler version of my app to make it easier to understand my problem.

Normally I'd do sth like that:

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")
library("dplyr")

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        ),

        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("distPlot1"),
            plotOutput("distPlot2")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot1 <- renderPlotly({

        x <- faithful[, 2]

        plot_ly(x = x, type = "histogram")
    })

    output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({

        x <- faithful[, 2]

        hist(x)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

to obtain this:

[image]

But when I start to create ui on server side like here (edited part with more divs inside ui):

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")
library("dplyr")

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        ),

        mainPanel(
            htmlOutput("ui1"),
            uiOutput("ui2")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot1 <- renderPlotly({

        x <- faithful[, 2]

        plot_ly(x = x, type = "histogram")
    })

    output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({

        x <- faithful[, 2]

        hist(x)
    })

    output$ui1 <- renderUI({

        show <- h1("lfkhg")
        show <- paste0(show, plotlyOutput("distPlot1") %>% as.character())

        HTML(show)

    })

    output$ui2 <- renderUI({

        show <- h1("lfkhg")
        show <- paste0(show, plotOutput("distPlot2") %>% as.character())

        HTML(show)

    })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Plotly plot does not appear...

[image]

Do you know why and how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know why you need `%>% HTML()` in there as it works for me without it. Also if you want to add more things into the `renderUI` then simply use `tagList` and combine them together, here I will add `h1` as per your comment

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")
library("dplyr")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("ui1"),
      uiOutput("ui2")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlotly({
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    plot_ly(x = x, type = "histogram")
  })

  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2]
    hist(x)
  })

  output$ui1 <- renderUI({
    tagList(h1("lfkhg"),plotlyOutput("distPlot1"))
  })

  output$ui2 <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("distPlot2")
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain why then you need `%>% as.character() %>% HTML()` for `ui2`?

Comment: you dont need that either, i removed it

Comment: Because when I need this UI part to contain also for examle h1, then I need to do something like this: `show <- h1("lfkhg")
            show <- paste0(show, plotlyOutput("distPlot1") %>% as.character())

            HTML(show)`. Without this `as.character()` and `HTML()` it won't work. I just need to paste there many smaller parts to obtain this UI. I wanted to make this example simple so it looks strange maybe.

Comment: @Marta that wasn't in the original example, so its still not clear to me. Do you want to add more `divs` inside the `renderUI`?

Comment: Yes, I want. I can edit my question. I just wanted it to be simple, sorry for that.